# agrupar los resultados de una consulta en un sola fila

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo una vista en sqlServer en la cual hago el siguiente select

```
SELECT mes
      ,P117_Dias_Trabajados
      ,P004_Dias_Falta
      ,P002_Dias_Permisos_CG
      ,P003_Dias_Permisos_SG
      ,P003_Dias_Licenicas_Comun
      ,P003_Dias_Licencias_Loborales
      ,P003_Dias_No_Contratados
  FROM v_TPersonal_Asistencia 
  WHERE ficha='11117454'
```

el cual me arroja el siguiente resultado (imagen1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que me muestre una fila por cada `mes` (imagen2)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
he intentado agrupar los valores por `mes` pero me da el siguiente error:
La columna 'v_TPersonal_Asistencia.P117_Dias_Trabajados' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.
```

y al agregar los demas campos me muestra el mismo resultado que en la imagen1,

Comment: Cómo es la consulta que has hecho para agruparlos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a agrupar sólo por mes, debes usar funciones de agregación en el resto de las columnas (por ejemplo `SUM`):

```
SELECT mes
      ,SUM(P117_Dias_Trabajados) P117_Dias_Trabajados
      ,SUM(P004_Dias_Falta) P004_Dias_Falta
      ,SUM(P002_Dias_Permisos_CG) P002_Dias_Permisos_CG
      ,SUM(P003_Dias_Permisos_SG) P003_Dias_Permisos_SG
      ,SUM(P003_Dias_Licenicas_Comun) P003_Dias_Licenicas_Comun
      ,SUM(P003_Dias_Licencias_Loborales) P003_Dias_Licencias_Loborales
      ,SUM(P003_Dias_No_Contratados) P003_Dias_No_Contratados
  FROM v_TPersonal_Asistencia 
  WHERE ficha='11117454'
  GROUP BY mes;
```

Comment: Hola Lamak, desconozco el motivo pero lo había intentado pero no me funciono me decía algo de se elimino un valor null y se detenía la consulta, gracias me funciono

Comment: @Kevin ese mensaje es una advertencia que lanzan las funciones de agregación, para alertar que simplemente obvían los valores NULL de los resultados

Comment: Entiendo gracias